# SBT Test-Dependencies in Multiprojects: Make the Test-Code Available to Dependent Projects

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

I've a SBT multi-project where some projects have dependencies to each other. Like this:

```
 lazy val coreProject: Project = Project(
    id = "core-project",
    base = file("./core-project"),
    // other stuff
    ))

  lazy val extensions: Project = Project(
    id = "extensions",
    base = file("./extensions"),
    dependencies = Seq(coreProject)
  )
```

Now I have some test-code in the 'core' project in the test-folder. There are also stuff like mocks and test-utilities. Now I would like to use those test utilities in the tests of the extensions. For production code this works, since I've declared a dependency. However it seems that dependency doesn't hold for the tests. When I run the tests I get compilation error for missing classes. Those classes are from the test-code in the core-project.

How can I tell sbt that the dependency also should include the test-code for the test-scope? So that I can reuse my mocks in the test-code of the 'exension'-project?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Like so:

```
dependencies = Seq(coreProject % "compile->compile;test->test")
```

This is discussed in the section "Per-configuration classpath dependencies" in then [Getting-Started-Multi-Project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Multi-Project) guide.

Comment: Just so others aren't confused here, this is suggesting that you set the dependencies in the Project definition (not the library dependencies).

Comment: For non SBT ninzas, can you show more of the build file please? A definition like `lazy val foo = project.settings(...).dependencies(Seq(bar % "compile->compile;test->test"))` doesn't work. @RyanGross, would you?

Answer (score 61):

You can also do this with a `.dependsOn(coreProject % "compile->compile;test->test")` after the initial project declaration.

```
lazy val coreProject = Project("core-project")
lazy val extensions = Project("extensions").dependsOn(coreProject % "compile->compile;test->test")
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Multi-Project.html#Per-configuration+classpath+dependencies