# Depending on custom myproject-test Maven artifact in sbt

Tags: sbt

How can I publish a myproject-test.jar in one sbt project, containing my test classes, and depend on both that, and myproject.jar, in another sbt project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for sbt 0.11.3.

In the first sbt project:

```
publishArtifact in Test := true
```

In the second one, specify the dependency like this:

```
"com.example" % "myproject" % "42" classifier "test" classifier ""
```

(i.e. add the two classifiers to your existing dependency specification.)

However, you probably want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193904/sbt-test-dependencies-in-multiprojects-make-the-test-code-available-to-dependen) instead in the second project.