# Reading resources from a macro in an SBT project

Tags: scala, maven, classpath, sbt, scala-macros

Suppose I have a Scala project with three sub-projects, with files like this:

```
foo/src/main/scala/Foo.scala
foo/src/main/resources/foo.txt

bar/src/main/scala/Bar.scala
bar/src/main/resources/bar.txt

baz/src/main/scala/Baz.scala
baz/src/main/resources/baz.txt
```

`Foo.scala` contains a simple macro that reads a resource at a given path:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object Foo {
  def countLines(path: String): Option[Int] = macro countLines_impl

  def countLines_impl(c: Context)(path: c.Expr[String]) = {
    import c.universe._

    path.tree match {
      case Literal(Constant(s: String)) => Option(
        this.getClass.getResourceAsStream(s)
      ).fold(reify(None: Option[Int])) { stream =>
        val count = c.literal(io.Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines.size)
        reify(Some(count.splice))
      }
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Need a literal path!")
    }
  }
}
```

If the resource can be opened, `countLines` returns the number of lines; otherwise it's empty.

The other two Scala source files just call this macro:

```
object Bar extends App {
  println(Foo.countLines("/foo.txt"))
  println(Foo.countLines("/bar.txt"))
  println(Foo.countLines("/baz.txt"))
}
```

And:

```
object Baz extends App {
  println(Foo.countLines("/foo.txt"))
  println(Foo.countLines("/bar.txt"))
  println(Foo.countLines("/baz.txt"))
}
```

The contents of the resources don't really matter for the purposes of this question.

If this is a Maven project, I can easily configure it so that the root project aggregates the three sub-projects and `baz` depends on `bar`, which depends on `foo`. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/5792171) for the gory details.

With Maven everything works as expected. `Bar` can see the resources for `foo` and `bar`:

```
Some(1)
Some(2)
None
```

And `Baz` can see all of them:

```
Some(1)
Some(2)
Some(3)
```

Now I try the same thing with SBT:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyProject extends Build {
  lazy val root: Project = Project(
    id = "root", base = file("."),
    settings = commonSettings
  ).aggregate(foo, bar, baz)

  lazy val foo: Project = Project(
    id = "foo", base = file("foo"),
    settings = commonSettings
  )

  lazy val bar: Project = Project(
    id = "bar", base = file("bar"),
    settings = commonSettings,
    dependencies = Seq(foo)
  )

  lazy val baz: Project = Project(
    id = "baz", base = file("baz"),
    settings = commonSettings,
    dependencies = Seq(bar)
  )

  def commonSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.2",
    libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % _)
  )
}
```

But now `Bar` can only see the resources in `foo`:

```
Some(1)
None
None
```

And `Baz` can only see `foo` and `bar`:

```
Some(1)
Some(2)
None
```

What's going on here? This SBT build file seems to me to be a pretty literal translation of the Maven configuration. I have no problem opening a console in the `bar` project and reading `/bar.txt`, for example, so why can't these projects see their own resources when calling a macro?

Comment: @0__: Thanks, I should have mentioned that—yes, they're there (and are available from non-macro code both in the console and in the project source).

Comment: Not a macro expert, but it must be a class loader issue IMO. At what points exactly is `this.getClass.getResourceAsStream` executed? Perhaps you need to use the context or something else as the class loader reference? No clue...

Comment: @0__: I'm assuming it's something like that, but none of my flailing hit a solution, and the fact that it works as expected in the Maven case makes me think it should be something simple.

Comment: Just thinking... Since the resource is queried at compile time, you assume that it is on the class path. But I wonder, wouldn't it be perfectly legal if sbt excluded the dependencies resources from the compile class path—after all in "normal" (non-macro) conditions there would be no way to access those resources anyway. [Maybe related problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193904/sbt-test-dependencies-in-multiprojects-make-the-test-code-available-to-dependen)

Comment: Looking at the [classpaths doc](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Classpaths), maybe you need to add something like `unmanagedResources in Compile <++= ...` or `unmanagedClasspath in Compile <++= ...`. Using `show` from the console you may be able to find out if everything you need is in the compile time class path.

Comment: An alternative would be using System.getProperties to communicate between SBT and macros. That's not very pretty, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SBT does not add the resources of the current project into the build class-path. Probably because it is rarely needed.

You just have to pipe one (the resources) into the other (the classpath):

```
def commonSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.2",
  libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % _),
  // add resources of the current project into the build classpath
  unmanagedClasspath in Compile <++= unmanagedResources in Compile
)
```

In that project you would only need that for `bar` and `baz`.

**UPDATE:** Since sbt 0.13, `<+=` and `<++=` are unnecessary (and undocumented) thanks to the new macro-based syntax:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
unmanagedClasspath in Compile ++= (unmanagedResources in Compile).value
```

Comment: this adds resource files, not resource directories. See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1965#issuecomment-376958438 for the real fix