# Factoring libraryDependencies in multi project Build.sbt

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, multi-project

I'm trying to write a concise multi project Build.sbt, so I tried to put all library dependencies in root project and then make others depends on it. My Build.sbt looks like the following:

```
object KataBuild extends Build {

        lazy val fizzBuzz = Project(
            id = "fizzBuzz", 
            base = file("fizzBuzz"),
            settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
                name := "fizzBuzz",
                version := "1.0",
                scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
            )
        )

        lazy val kata = Project(
            id = "scala-kata", 
            base = file("."),
            settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
                name := "scala-kata",
                version := "1.0",
                scalaVersion := "2.10.3",
                libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.0" % "test"
                )
            )
        ) aggregate(fizzBuzz)

        fizzBuzz dependsOn(kata)

}
```

But running test from the main project (scala-kata) fails to build test for fizzBuzz. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193904/sbt-test-dependencies-in-multiprojects-make-the-test-code-available-to-dependen). In short, `fizzBuzz.dependsOn(kata)` means that its *compile configuration* depends on the kata's compile configuration, but you want to link the *test* configurations.

The ['Per-configuration classpath dependencies'](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project#per-configuration-classpath-dependencies) section of the sbt docs show you how you can make a `test->test` dependency instead.

---

However, if you are not going to use `kata`'s test sources but are just looking for a way to include Scala-Test in `fizzBuzz`, just add it explicitly to `fizzBuzz`'s library dependencies, too. You can define a helper value

```
lazy val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.0" % "test"
```

Then you can add it to be sub project's library dependencies (`libraryDependencies += scalaTest`).

Comment: Yes I don't need kata's test sources in subprojects. I just wanted the library dependency to be shared (declared just in kata project, with subProjects depending on it). So, as I understand this is not possible, I have to add it explicitly to all subProjects, or declare all the tests for subprojects inside kata/src/test. Am I right?